# Using multiple Ember apps with the same Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Hi I have a built out Ember app which works with a single rails backend. I would like to now have several other Ember apps working with rails but i am not sure how to make it work. I am using Oauth, devise and rolify to send logged in users to different ember apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put all of your ember apps in separate folders inside the Rail's public folder?  For example, if you have 2 ember apps, admin and publisher, your folder structure can be something like this:

```
/app
/public
  /admin
    /index.html --> ember app
  /publisher
    /index.html --> ember app
```

You'll need to define a couple of routes in config/routes.rb, one for admin and one for publisher so that when someone goes to a URL that matches your ember app, the correct file gets served.  You can try something like this:

```
  get '/admin/*path' => redirect('/admin/')
  get '/publisher/*path' => redirect('/publisher/')
```

Note that while the above route examples will work, you'll want to do a rewrite instead of a redirect.

Doing it this way will future proof your solution in case you migrate your apps to Ember CLI in the future.  With Ember CLI, you can just build your ember apps into the public/admin and public/publisher folders in the future.